# ¿Se puede pasar un operador como argumento de una función en python?

Tags: python, operador

Quiero saber si puedo incluir dentro de los argumentos de una función en `Python` a un operador.

Por ejemplo, defino la función:

```
def operacion(x, y, op):
    print(x op y)
```

para después llamar la función:

```
operacion(5, 4, +)
```

y que dé como resultado:

> 9

Answer (score 3):

No puedes pasar un operador como argumento de una función como tal, para empezar porque eso sería sintaxis no válida (como seguro has comprobado). No obstante lo que si puedes hacer es pasar una cadena que represente el operador (`'+'` en vez de `+`) y usar el módulo [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html) de la biblioteca estándar que exporta un conjunto de funciones correspondientes a los operadores intrínsecos de Python.

Algo así:

```
import operator

def operacion(x, y, op):
    operadores = {
         '+': operator.add,
         '-': operator.sub,
         '*': operator.mul,
         '/': operator.truediv
          }
    fop = operadores.get(op)
    if fop is not None:
        print(fop(x, y))
    else:
        raise ValueError("Operador no válido")
```

> ```
> >>> operacion(5, 4, "+")
> 9
> >>> operacion(5, 4, "-")
> 1
> >>> operacion(5, 4, "*")
> 20
> >>> operacion(5, 4, "/")
> 1.25
> ```

Solo he definido las cuatro operaciones aritméticas básicas, pero puedes extender los operadores aceptados que necesites buscando su equivalente en el módulo `operator` y agregándolos al diccionario `operadores`, por ejemplo, para la potencia sería añadir la pareja clave/valor

```
'**': operator.pow
```

Una ventaja de este enfoque es que puedes usar cualquier cadena para denotar un operador, por ejemplo, si quieres que la `x` actúe como operador e multiplicación basta con añadir la pareja de claves:

```
'x': operator.mul,
'X': operator.mul
```

tampoco estás restringido a los operadores de Python, puedes definir cualquier otro "operador" y asociarlo aun callable cualquiera. Por ejemplo, para habilitar a la función para calcular el máximo común divisor y mínimo común múltiplo de dos números podemos hacer algo así:

```
import operator
import math

def operacion(x, y, op):
    operadores = {
         '+': operator.add,
         '-': operator.sub,
         '*': operator.mul,
         '/': operator.truediv,
         '**': operator.pow, 
         'MCD': math.gcd,
         'MCM': lambda a, b: (a * b) // math.gcd(a, b)
          }
    fop = operadores.get(op)
    if fop is not None:
        print(fop(x, y))
    else:
        raise ValueError("Operador no válido")
```

> ```
> >>> operacion(20, 32, 'MCD')
> 4
> >>> operacion(20, 32, 'MCM')
> 160
> ```

---

Además de usar una cadena y un diccionario para mapear, hay otras posibilidades. Por ejemplo, no hay ningún problema en pasar una referencia a la función del módulo `operator` a otra función:

```
import operator

def operacion(x, y, op):
    print(op(x, y))

operacion(4, 5, operator.add)
```

---

Se podría usar también `eval`. El problema principal es que `eval` evalúa cualquier cadena que sea una expresión en código Python válido, por lo que debes sanear los argumentos y comprobar que son seguros a fin de evitar posibles ataques de inyección de código si tu función procesa datos que provengan de entradas de usuario.

Esta es la razón principal por la que generalmente se recomienda evitar `eval`. Obviamente esto dependerá del uso que des a tu app, si estás creando una calculadora de uso personal esto es prácticamente irrelevante, pero si es una calculadora online en la que la función se ejecuta en el servidor es potencialmente un fallo de seguridad crítico.

```
def operacion(x, y, op):
    operadores = {'+', '-', '*', '/'}  # Operadores permitidos
    types = (int, float, complex)      # Tipos de operandos permitidos
    if not isinstance(x, types) or not isinstance(y, types):
        raise ValueError("Operando no válido")
    if not op in operadores:
        raise ValueError("Operador no válido")

    print(eval(f'{x}{op}{y}'))
```